# changing a grid position with another with longpress android GridView

Tags: android, gridview, swap, long-press

I have a gridView of images on my app and i want to implement long press to swap  two grids with the animation

example: user long press on one grid and can drag it and drop on another and swap their position

how can i do that ?

Comment: What you have done so far? please show your efforts?

Comment: try these libraries https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview  and https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

Comment: @AndyDeveloper i have the grid view filled with images , nothing more